# creating a separate column where the score is inverse of the ranking in pandas

Tags: pandas, rank

I am ranking a bunch of movies using pandas, from 1-100, and I was wondering how to create a separate column called score where the scores are inverse. for example:

rank score

1. 100
2. 99
3. 98

all the way to

100. 1

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if already you have rank column with the values 1 to 100,

```
df['rank'] = range(1, 101)
df['score'] = range(len(df),0,-1)
```

Comment: hmm filling it from 100 to 1 doesn't work. it gives the error message:

ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (100)

but the same technique works if it's incremental from 1 to 100, using range(1, 101)

Comment: now changed the code.. it works for me

Comment: glad to hear you.. kindly accept and upvote the answer